# How to implement re-init logic in servelt programming？

Tags: tomcat, servlets

My servlet applications （java+tomcat）aims to provide an online cityid-temperature mapping. The mapping rules is loaded from file on the disk in the **init()** function. But the file updates everyday, so I need something like **reload or reinit** function to reload the file into memory, which standard servlet does not provide. 
How to implement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you start up, save the timestamp of the file somehow.  Every so often, compare the saved  timestamp with that of the file.  If the file is newer, then reload the file.

You could store the timestamp any number of ways.  For example, cache a variable in the Application Context. Or, on startup, create an empty file that with the current time so you know when you last loaded the file.  Use the empty file's timestamp as your reference value, and recreate the empty file when you reload.